# Unity set GUI element adjustable for all screens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making mobile game and I have script with GUI to show score and highscore. When I playing game on different devices, somewhere is font of score and highscore good, somewhere is very,very small.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OnGUI2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public static OnGUI2D O2G;

    public static int score;
    int highScore;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        O2G = this;
        score = 0;
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore1",0);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.black;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(14,70,100,20), "S: " +score);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(14,85,100,20), "HS: " +highScore);
    }

    public void CheckHighScore ()
    {
        if (score > highScore)
        {
            Debug.Log("Saving Score");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore1", score);
        }

    }

}
```

So, my question is how can I make GUI element adjustable for all screens?

Thanks,
Kind regards

SOLVE 12/25/2015: Dito. You should create a Canvas and place a Label on it, the Canvas object has several scaling options sothat you can react to different resolutions / orientations appropiately. (unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui for more resources) -Maximilian Gerhardt

Comment: Why not use new UI system (Unity3D 5)? It scales just fine with its content size fitters and canvas size scaling.

Comment: Dito. You should create a `Canvas` and place a `Label` on it, the `Canvas` object has several scaling options sothat you can react to different resolutions / orientations appropiately. (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui for more resources)

Comment: Thanks bro. I fixed everything.